# SQL Server 2008 R2 job reschedule on Holidays

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, job-scheduling

I have a SQL Server job that runs biweekly on Monday. I also have a table with a list of holiday dates. I want to be able to skip running my job on any Monday that is a holiday and instead run that iteration of the job the next day.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the job on Monday and Tuesday.

For the job, start with the logic:

```
if (cast(getdate() as date) in (select days from holidaytable) and
    datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Monday'
   ) or
   (cast(getdate()-1 as date) not in (select days from holidaytable) and
    datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Tuesday'
   )
begin
    don't run the job now (whatever you want to do to log that)
end;
rest of the code for the job
```

Comment: perfect I was thinking of recreating jobs this is so much cleaner ... thanks for the approach